Error en sitio web wordpress, mensaje en la parte superior del sitio
tengo un problema en mi sitio web wordpress. Para empezar cuando ingreso me redirecciona a otra web diferente y cuando logro ingresar al panel de administración me sale un mensaje en la parte de arriba con este codigo, ese codigo sale en todas las paginas.
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* - [L] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] - [L] 
Deny from all


Te han colado malware seguramente: https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-malicioso-en-instalacion-de-wp-infectada/
